# Python not recognized anymore

Tags: python

I had installed python 3.9, and everything worked just fine - I wanted to use the wordcloud module, but after failed attempts I realized it was because it wasn't set up for 3.9, so I tried installing python 3.8 - after I uninstalled python 3.9, nothing works anymore

Everytime I type "python + nameoffile.py", it says that python isn't recognized, and I am stuck

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling python 3 times, nothing - it still comes out as not recognized.

Did someone else encounter the same problem or did I seriously mess up my system?

Comment: Please show `echo $PATH`

Comment: Welcome to SO, what is the command line output that you got

Comment: This is not a Python question.

Comment: If the installation was successful, you'll want to test that `/path/to/python -v` still works and returns the version you want

Comment: What platform are you on: Linux? Windows?

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa Python questions don't have to be about writing Python code. Questions about installing and using programming tools are on topic, too.

Comment: @JohnKugelman IMHO questions about system administration belong on SuperUser, not SO.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows you can try using

```
py nameoffile.py
```

You cannot use python command unless you add it to your $PATH variable. But you can use py command that comes default when you install python on windows machine. py command is same as python

Comment: This is rather a suggestion better suited for comment than an answer. You should try to explain what this command does and why it would help.

Comment: You cannot use python command unless you add it to your $PATH variable. But you can use py command that comes default when you install python on windows machine. py command is same as python

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason, I'm forgetful and impatient and in every occasion I didn't click on "add python to PATH"